# Run a callback on bound fields of a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-web-developer

I want to process a field retrieved from the database for a Gridview to check to see if the information in it is a hyperlink. If it is, I want to generate a link from it, otherwise just leave it as raw text. At the moment the field in the Gridview looks like:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtReference" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried modifying what's in the 'Text' attribute of the ItemTemplate but no matter what I put in I get errors on pageload. How can I dynamically modify what's sent to the browser based on the specific info bound in this field?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using both a `Label` and a `HyperLink` in my `TemplateField`, showing the `HyperLink` (and hiding the `Label`) if the bound text qualifies as a proper URL.

The following ASP.NET sets up the potential HTML to output:

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblReference" runat="server" Visible='<%# !isTextHyperlink(Eval("Reference")) %>' Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'/>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlReference" runat="server" Visible='<%# isTextHyperlink(Eval("Reference")) %>' Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I added a function in the pages 'codebehind' like this:

**C#**

```
protected bool isTextHyperlink(object refobj)
{
    string refstring = refobj.ToString();
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(refstring);
        return Uri.CheckSchemeName(uri.Scheme);
    }
    catch
    {
        // not a valid uri (that Uri can construct with)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Many thanks to Brissles for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use both a `Label` and a `HyperLink` in your `TemplateField` and show the `HyperLink` (and hide the `Label`) if the bound text qualifies as a proper URL. You can do this using a codebehind function that returns a bool to the `Visible` property, something like this:

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsTextHyperlink(Eval("Reference")) %>' Text='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'/>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hl" runat="server" Visible='<%# !IsTextHyperlink(Eval("Reference")) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Reference") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**C#**

```
protected bool IsTextHyperlink(object text)
{
    bool IsHyperLink = false;
    ...
    // check if text qualifies as hyperlink
    ...
    return IsHyperLink ; 
}
```

Note using type `object` for the IsHyperLink function parameter, as Eval() returns an object, just cast it to a String.

You'd want to also format your `Text` property of your `HyperLink` to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GridView.OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx) method like

```
protected virtual void yourGV_OnRowDataBound(object sender, gridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = e.Row 
}
```

inside that you can access the controls in the row with [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) for example.